# python combine 2 columns into 1 row

Tags: python, pandas

Hello there i have the following dataframe:

```
   Name      Lastname     ticket        
0   Peter       Pan        Ticket1
1   Null       Null         $20
```

i want to make it look like this:

```
   Name      Lastname     ticket   ticketprice     
0   Peter       Pan        Ticket1      $20 
1    NULL       NULL        Null        Null
```

but it seems to be really difficult for me. Does anyone know how this works?

Comment: What happens to David Miller?

Comment: oh that one was wrong, i updated it

Comment: Is one line out of two a ticket price?

Comment: the second line is a line just for the ticketprice

Comment: Ok ,then you could use df['ticket_price'] = df['ticket'].shift(-1) on a copy of that column and that should work for you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that your odd columns contain the ticket price, one way you could do this is by copying the column into another `ticketprice` column and shifting that column up by one like so:

```
import pandas as pd
    
df['ticket_price'] = df['ticket'].shift(-1)
df = df.iloc[::2]
```

Then delete all rows that have an even index to remove the empty line. In the example above df is the pandas dataframe containing your base data.

Answer (score -1):

Use loc to slice the frame into every other row and assign the value (assuming every other row is associated with the ticket price above).

Assuming this frame

```
Name    Lastname    ticket
0   Peter   Pan Ticket1
1   Null    Null    $20
2   john    doe ticket2
3   Null    Null    $30
```

then

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.loc[0::2, 'ticketprice'] = df.iloc[1::2, 2].values
df.iloc[1::2] = np.nan
print(df)

    Name Lastname   ticket ticketprice
0  Peter      Pan  Ticket1         $20
1    NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN
2   john      doe  ticket2         $30
3    NaN      NaN      NaN         NaN
```